# Absolute position in pixmap

Tags: qt, position

I am looking to get the absolute position from the mouse into the Pixmap.

My pixmap is far bigger than the window so I have put a scrollbar.
But if I want to get the absolute position from my mouse into the pixmap the position is false (it is in comparison to the window frame).

```
void ImageViewer::ImageViewer(){
    imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap()); //QLabel
    imageLabel->setFixedWidth(imageLabel->width()*2);
    imageLabel->setFixedHeight(imageLabel->height()*2);
    scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
    scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
    scrollArea->setWidget(imageLabel);
    setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
 }

void ImageViewer:: mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    //How to get position into the Pixmap?
}
```

Comment: Absolute position as in, the position of the mouse within the screen? Your phrasing is kind of unclear.

Comment: Not in the screen but in the pixmap which is much bigger than the sizebog the app window. The pixmap should guve the coordinates.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example that actually runs?